# Where can I find FDist2 executable?

Tags: bioinformatics

I am trying to download the program FDist2 ([Beaumont and Nichols 1996](http://rspb.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/263/1377/1619.short)) for Mac but for some reason it appears that all the links I find are broken.

It appears that the program [Lositan](http://popgen.net/soft/lositan/) is an faster implementation of FDist2 but in my understanding Lositan works only through a GUI and not via the command line (and given the number of analyses I want to perform I need to be able to run this algorithm from the command line).

Comment: I found this [link](http://www.maths.bris.ac.uk/~mamab/software/) in Mark Beaumont's [web site](http://www.maths.bris.ac.uk/~mamab). The links seem to work. I am not completely sure whether this is a question for this forum though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Lotterhos and Whitlock 2014](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/mec.12725/full) recoded fdist2 in R and it can be found [here](http://datadryad.org/resource/doi:10.5061/dryad.v8d05) on Dryad.

Answer (score 3):

The [link](http://www.maths.bris.ac.uk/~mamab/software/) that ddiez has mentioned, has a download [link for a zip file](http://www.maths.bris.ac.uk/~mamab/software/fdist2.zip) (fidist2). The zip file contains windows executables and C-codes. Just compile the C-codes in your terminal.

This is from the readme:

> The .exe files are pc binaries, which is only what most people want. I
>   include the source file in case anyone wants to play with them. In
>   this case compilation is e.g.:
>
> ```
> gcc -o fdist2 -O fdist2.c -lm
> gcc -o cplot -O cplot.c as100.c as99.c -lm
> gcc -o datacal -O datacal.c -lm
> ```

*Actually in the readme, the first compile command says `fdist.c` (no such file) instead of `fdist2.c`. I corrected that here.*

Your system should have `gcc`. I tried compiling in my system (linux) and it works. It should work in Mac too.

Comment: OS X doesn't come with a compiler by default, but if you install XCode and the command-line tools, you'll get `clang`, which works (in this case) very much in the same manner.

Comment: @MattDMo ohh okay.. I didn't know that... That's bad .. [This](http://www.mkyong.com/mac/how-to-install-gcc-compiler-on-mac-os-x/) page says that `XCode` comes with `gcc` (don't know what version but once you have a compiler you can always compile the other versions).

Comment: Well, I'm avoiding a lot of "nerd" details. I think the command `gcc` will work from the command line once the proper tools are installed (@Remi.b, make sure you run XCode first!). The problem I'm running into currently is that the files aren't compiling. Remi will need to find a C expert, I think....

Comment: Yes, the compilation fails on Mac. I'll try to figure this out (eventually with some help from the StackOverflow community) and suggest an edit. Thank you!

Comment: @Remi.b Have a look at [this](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2015/05/01/compiling-gcc-5-mac-os-x/) page.. Once you compile `gcc` on your system, you won't have much trouble. Having `gcc` in your system would be useful for other purposes in future as well.